# yes | apt-get install --fix-broken

Tags: apt, dpkg, yes

I am trying to write a non-interactive system update script.

Question:

if the following works well:

```
yes | dpkg --configure -a
```

will the following work also very well?:

```
yes | apt-get install --fix-broken
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have `-y` or `--yes` or `--assume-yes` parameters in `apt-get`.

Try something like

```
sudo apt-get install -y <package-name>
```

**Details:**

The [manual page of apt-get](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) (You can also refer to manual page with `man apt-get` command) mentions:

> **-y, --yes, --assume-yes**
>
> Automatic yes to prompts. Assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
>   changing a held package or removing an essential package, occurs then
>   apt-get will abort.  Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

Contrary to this parameter, you also have

> **--assume-no**
>
> Automatic "no" to all prompts. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-No.

**Edit**

For Vlastimil's comment, I tried

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken --assume-yes
```

And it works. The `--fix-broken` part of the command can be replaced with `-f`
and `--assume-yes` with `-y` or `--yes` for convenience. This will not install any package in perticular but "can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution", as mentioned on the manual page.